# Ajax loades content via form and next page history back

Tags: jquery, forms, history

is there a possibility to show ajax loaded content after clicking back-button on next page. My problem is, that I have html-form where post-data are shown via ajax request. This is a search-form where different search results are show. In results user can click detail-page. And now I want to show search results again after clicking back-button on detail page. here is my ajax code for form:

```
var $form = $("#searchform");
                                var method = $form.attr("method") ? $form.attr("method").toUpperCase() : "GET";
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: $form.attr("action"),
                                    dataType:'html',
                                    data: $form.serialize(),
                                    type: method,
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        $loadajax.html('');

                                        $("#searchresults").html(data);

                                        var newheight = $('#suchergebnis').height();
                                        //$('#loadajax_o').animate( {height: newheight}, function() {
                                            $('html, body').animate({
                                                scrollTop: $('#searchresults').offset().top
                                            }, 800);    
                                        //} );

                                        $("#ima_transparency").fadeOut();
                                        $("#loaderImage").fadeOut();

                                    },
                                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                      alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    }
                                });
```

Thanks for helping!
Martin

Comment: Do with window.history.pushState() sample https://jsfiddle.net/fJ9wq/

Comment: thank you - but seems not working with post data with following code: 

...$("#ima_transparency").fadeOut();
           $("#loaderImage").fadeOut();
           
           var targetUrl = window.location.href,
                  targetTitle = 'Konfigurator';
           
           window.history.pushState({url: "" + targetUrl + ""}, targetTitle, targetUrl);
              setCurrentPage(targetUrl);